# Error while installing PHP 7.1 for Mac (with Homebrew)

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install PHP 7.1 with Homebrew.

According to the Homebrew site I should type

`brew install exolnet/deprecated/php@7.1`

and all I get is

`configure: error: Please reinstall the iconv library.`

Reinstall does not help. Current version libiconv is 1.16.

How fix this error?

Answer (score 25):

Icu4c reinstallation made me force reinstall PHP8, which broke the purpose for me. So, I have found some new repositories where you don't need to hassle with this icu4c stuff at all:

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@5.6
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.0
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.1
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.2
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.3
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.1
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.2
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.3
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.4
```

First, delete all php installations with a command something like `brew uninstall "php*"` and `brew unlink php@7.1`

You may also need to `untap` other taps. I had to run

```
brew untap exolnet/deprecated
```

to install properly.

Then, if you want, delete the /usr/local/etc/php folder

then install one of the packages I've linked above.

Worked Nicely for PHP 7.1:

```
➜  ~ php -v
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Dec  1 2020 01:14:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

You can also quickly switch between php versions with a command like:

```
brew unlink php && brew link --overwrite --force php@7.2
```

etc.

The GitHub repository: https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php

The source where I found these packages: [here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions).

Answer (score 9):

Try with the following

```
brew install openldap libiconv
brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated
brew install php@7.1
```

For any more details, check this guide

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions

Comment: Awesome, for a first answer!  All else had failed.

Comment: No longer works. Best answer (as of 2021-04-15) is @Arda 's answer below.

Comment: >brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated

Fails with
brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on Big Sur:

```
brew tap shivammathur/homebrew-php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.64.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.33/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
```

Solution for me was to first download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb manually (since installing formula directly renders the error `Calling Installation of icu4c from a GitHub commit URL is disabled!`) and then:

```
$ brew reinstall icu4c.rb
```

Next, copy the .dylib files from the older icu4c version somewhere temporary:

```
$ mkdir ~/temp
$ cp /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.4/lib/*.dylib ~/temp
```

Then, reinstall icu4c:

```
$ brew reinstall icu4c
```

Run php 7.1 and copy each necessary .dylib file back to your current icu4c lib folder, accordingly, until php 7.1 renders no errors.